# Dropdown Menu Open width Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a problem with a drop down menu that must remain open to the click.
After the menu is open, you can click the link inside and the menu item just clicked.

How can I do to remedy the `preventDefault` ?

Menu HTML:

```
<nav class="main-menu">
    <ul id="" class="menu">

        <li>
            <a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">Menu One</a>
            <div class="sub-menu">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="http://www.google.uk" target="_blank">test test test</a></li>
                    ... More links ...
                </ul>
            </div>
        </li>

        ... More items ...

    </ul>
</nav>
```

This is a portion of code

```
$('.main-menu li a').click(function(event) {        
    event.preventDefault();
    $('.main-menu').find('.sub-menu').removeClass('open');
    $(this).parent().find('.sub-menu').addClass('open');
});
```

An example is visible here [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/9m9rufqx/)

Answer (score 0):

Just remove

```
$('.main-menu').find('.sub-menu').removeClass('open');
```

[Here is a fiddle you can check out](https://jsfiddle.net/9m9rufqx/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of `event.preventDefault();`

Instead do like this

```
<a href="#" onclick="return false">
```

Then give each main menu a class name. And call the click event on that class.

https://jsfiddle.net/btevfik/9m9rufqx/3/

Answer (score 0):

You can replace your selector with a more targeted (`.menu > li > a`) :

```
$('.menu > li > a').click(function(event) {        
    event.preventDefault();
    $('.sub-menu.open').removeClass('open');
    $(this).parent().find('.sub-menu').addClass('open');
});
```

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/ewux4xca/)

Comment: We're almost there!
So, when the 'sub-menu' is open the top-level menu must become clickable (on google.uk).
Thank you very much !!

Comment: @jonnywalker , Since these menu items perform another action, you should register another handler for click event for these - [**Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/umg4Ly0z/). Or ultimately register click events for `a` with specifiied classes (so that you can mix actions) - [**Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/4gkLngL1/)